# Dismiss "... wants to know your location" dialog

Tags: java, selenium, dialog, geolocation, dismiss

I am using Selenium + Chromedriver to automate testing of a website.  One of the functionalities uses Location Services.  I have enabled the Location Service for the Chrome browser that I am using.

But when I run the test, the dialog pictured below shows.
[image]

The following code finds the alert - but the alert.dismiss() does not seem to work (i.e. the dialog is still present)

```
try {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.dismiss();
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
            // System.out.println("No alert for this test case.");
        }
```

How can the test code click the Allow button and have the dialog dismissed?  My goal is to click Allow.

--Sam--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("googlegeolocationaccess.enabled", true);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 2); // 1:allow 2:block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings", 1);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

you can also try setting     prefs.put("googlegeolocationaccess.enabled", false);

This will make all geo location access request to be blocked or accept by default according to the flag you set before running the driver

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The same dialog pops up even after I added prefs.put("googlegeolocationaccess.enabled", false);

Comment: @sp you have to set it to true and set prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation as 2 , use the code as it is

Comment: Thank you, @PDHide.   Now the code works like charm - the dialog in the image above is not shown in either case.

Comment: Just discovered that if the browser is instantiated in Incognito mode, the dialog to allow/disallow "Know your location" shows.  Is the code supposed to work only in non-Incognito mode?

Comment: I think in incognito location service is disabled so the code won't work I am not sure why

Comment: Thanks.  I guess, I won't run the tests in incognoto mode then :)

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign